# Set Global Variables in Function

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a problem where I am setting some global varaibles within a function. But when I go to access these global variables outside the function (in the main part of the script) those global varaibles were never set?

Why do the following global variables always equal `0` and not `1`? How can I set the global variables within my function?

```
currentUserClientID             = 0
currentUserMaxLicences          = 0
currentUserActivatedLicences    = 0

def setGlobals():
    currentUserClientID             = 1
    currentUserMaxLicences          = 1
    currentUserActivatedLicences    = 1
    print "Set Globals"
    print currentUserClientID
    print currentUserMaxLicences
    print currentUserActivatedLicences

setGlobals()

print "Global Values"
print currentUserClientID
print currentUserMaxLicences
print currentUserActivatedLicences
```

Output:

```
Set Globals
1
1
1
Global Values
0
0
0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `global` keyword:

```
def setGlobals():
    global currentUserClientID, currentUserMaxLicences, currentUserActivatedLicences
    currentUserClientID             = 1
    currentUserMaxLicences          = 1
    currentUserActivatedLicences    = 1
    print "Set Globals"
    print currentUserClientID, currentUserMaxLicences, currentUserActivatedLicences
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the variables as global. Put the `global` keyword before each variable declaration inside the function.

```
def setGlobals():
    global currentUserClientID
    global currentUserMaxLicences
    global currentUserActivatedLicences
    currentUserClientID = 1
    currentUserMaxLicenses = 1
    currentUserActivatedLicenses = 1
    print "Set Globals"
    print currentUserClientID
    print currentUserMaxLicences
    print currentUserActivatedLicences
```

Comment: That'll give you a SyntaxError :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed it :) forgot exactly the syntax.